# jqgrid multiselect issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having a strange issue with jqgrid. when i select a row, row gets selected but checkbox is not getting checked and also when i select another row, previous rows does not get unselected rather its just keep adding to selection. so plzz help....

```
 $("#list9").jqGrid({
                url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['Report', 'Download'],
                colModel: [
          { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 610, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Download', index: 'Download', width: 300, align: 'left', sortable: false, formatter: LinkFormatter}],
                pager: jQuery('#pager9'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                sortname: 'Name',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                recordpos: 'left',
                viewrecords: true,
                loadonce: true,
                multiselect: true,
                caption: 'Docs Library',
                onSelectRow: function (rowid) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much experience with jqgrid but what I can tell from the [multiselect demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), if you have multiselect set to true, it is supposed to add additional rows not unselect them. So I do not understand what your problem is.

If you do not want to be able to select multiple rows, then do not set multiselect to true.

If this is not what you are looking for, we may need more information. If you could possibly create a demo using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), we may be able to help you more easily.

Comment: my main is to get the multiselection. I have set multiselect to true and can get the checkboxes in each row but problem is on row selection my checkbox do not get selected. and when i select other row my first selected row donot get unselected. do i need any special js file to include??

Comment: I found the issue. jqGrid takes the id as number but I was passing as string.